# Why spring boot @Value populating not working

Tags: java, spring, code-injection

I have a spring service:

```
@Service
public class AuthorizationServiceImpl implements AuthorizationService {

@Value("${local.address}")
private String localIP;

private final String LOCALHOST_IPV4 = "127.0.0.1";
private final String LOCALHOST_IPV6 = "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1";

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@Override
public boolean isAuthorized(String token, HttpServletRequest request) {
    try {
        TokenUserModel user = new TokenUserModel();
        user.setSessionID("");
        user = getTokenUserModel(token);
        IServiceAAA client = new ServiceAAA().getBasicHttpBindingIServiceAAA();
        int systemId = client.getUserSystemId("InvoiceAdmin");

        String xRealIP = request.getRemoteAddr();
        String ipAddress = xRealIP.equals(LOCALHOST_IPV4) || xRealIP.equals(LOCALHOST_IPV6) ? localIP : xRealIP;
        String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
        int response = client.checkPermissionAndUserData(user.getSessionID(), "Admin",
                userAgent,
                ipAddress, systemId, systemId, "");
        return response == 0;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new AuthorizationException(AuthorizationError.ERR_WHILE_AUTHORISATION);
    }
}
```

`@Value("${local.address}")`

`private String localIP;` - this line of code didn't working, not populating local.address field from application.properties:

```
local.address=10.10.16.13
```

Update:

1. I have 3 application properties file for spring profiles, named:
   `application.properties`, `application-dev.properties`, `application-prod.properties`.
   My current active profile is `application-dev.properties`
   ('spring.profiles.active=dev' - it's inside of my
   `application.properties` file).
2. I'm sure that 'local.address' property is defined in `application-dev.properties`

   ```
        local.address=10.10.16.13
   ```
3. `AuthorizationService` is a just an interface that `AutheroziationServiceImpl` implements.

```
public interface AuthorizationService {
    boolean isAuthorized(String token, HttpServletRequest request) throws UnsupportedEncodingException;

    void logout(String token) throws UnsupportedEncodingException;

    TokenUserModel getTokenUserModel(String token) throws UnsupportedEncodingException;
}
```

I'm using it in constructor of one of controllers:

```
@Autowired
    public AuthorizationController(AuthorizationService authorizationService) {
        this.authorizationService = authorizationService;
    }
    private final AuthorizationService authorizationService;
```

4. Yes, it's spring managed bean annotated as `@Service`

Comment: Do you have an exception? Can you post it?

Comment: Where is your properties file located? Is is it under ```src/main/resources``` and named ```application.properties```?

Comment: Also, confirm that the local.address is under right spirng profile inside application.properties. Another thing is, if the properties file name is `application.yml` the format is different.

Comment: How can you tell it didn't work? How do you use `AuthorizationServiceImpl`?

Comment: Is this a Spring managed bean?